# Apache Flink: How to close a fix size window when data is not received for certain period of time

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am trying to calculate the rate of incoming events per minute from a Kafka topic based on event time. I am using `TumblingEventTimeWindows` of 1 minute for this. The code snippet is given below. I have observed that if I am not receiving any event for a particular window, e.g. from 2.34 to 2.35, then the previous window of 2.33 to 2.34 does not get close. I understand the risk of losing data for the window of 2.33 to 2.34 (may happen due to system failure, bigger Kafka lag, etc.), but I cannot wait indefinitely. I need to close this window after waiting for a certain period of time, and subsequent windows can continue after the system recovers. How can I achieve this?

I am trying the following code which is giving the event count per minute for continuous flow of events.

```
    StreamExecutionEnvironment executionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    executionEnvironment.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(
            3,
            org.apache.flink.api.common.time.Time.of(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    ));
    executionEnvironment.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
    executionEnvironment.setParallelism(1);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "AllEventCountConsumerGroup");
    FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("event_input_topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties);
    DataStreamSource<String> kafkaDataStream = environment.addSource(kafkaConsumer);
    kafkaDataStream
            .flatMap(new EventFlatter())
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy
                    .<Entity>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                    .withTimestampAssigner((SerializableTimestampAssigner<Entity>) (element, recordTimestamp) -> element.getTimestamp()))
            .keyBy((KeySelector<Entity, String>) Entity::getTenant)
            .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(1)))
            .allowedLateness(Time.seconds(10))
            .aggregate(new EventCountAggregator())
            .addSink(eventRateProducer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given `forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(2))`, a window for the interval `[t, t + 1 minute)` won't close until after an event with `timestamp >= t + 1 minute + 2 seconds` is processed.

If your input stream can have long periods of idleness, and you can't wait until the stream resumes, then you'll have to either artificially advance the watermark after detecting idleness, or use a custom window `Trigger` that uses a combination of both event-time and processing-time timers.

For a watermark generator that detects idleness, here's [an example](https://github.com/aljoscha/flink/blob/6e4419e550caa0e5b162bc0d2ccc43f6b0b3860f/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/timestamps/ProcessingTimeTrailingBoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor.java), but it hasn't been updated to the new `WatermarkStrategy` API.

Comment: Just for my understanding, whether the new property [idlenessDetectionDuration](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13//dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#dealing-with-idle-sources) is more handy for this usecase or am I missing something?

Comment: The new `withIdleness` option will handle the case where a partition is idle, by arranging for that partition's idleness to be ignored. Thus whatever partitions still have input will control the watermarking. But this will not advance the watermark in the case where all partitions are idle.